# Making a gift from the given set of points

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics3d, recreational-mathematics

I have a set of points

```
pts = {{0.`, 3.2563310647907957`}, {1.1148148148148147`, 
4.23950315866573`}, {2.2296296296296294`, 
4.140162358470412`}, {3.3444444444444446`, 
4.00538956877346`}, {4.459259259259259`, 
0.6043122653889584`}, {5.5740740740740735`, 
0.3215124973296304`}, {6.688888888888889`, 
0.15878780480361337`}, {7.803703703703704`, 
0.17702871791741692`}, {8.918518518518518`, 
1.9691000091555526`}, {10.033333333333333`, 
3.1590899380474258`}, {11.148148148148147`, 
3.5733817560350354`}, {12.26296296296296`, 
2.9506973479415266`}, {13.377777777777778`, 
1.3527146214178898`}, {14.492592592592592`, 
1.2483870967741937`}, {15.607407407407408`, 
1.3054719687490461`}, {16.72222222222222`, 
1.0641407513657033`}, {17.837037037037035`, 
3.136124759666738`}, {18.951851851851853`, 
2.878914761803033`}, {20.066666666666666`, 
0.8222846156193732`}, {21.18148148148148`, 
0.7743858149967955`}, {22.296296296296294`, 
4.280709250160222`}, {23.41111111111111`, 
3.806970427564318`}, {24.52592592592592`, 
2.0106997894222842`}, {25.64074074074074`, 
0.736985381633961`}, {26.755555555555556`, 
0.49657277138584555`}, {27.87037037037037`, 
4.179006317331462`}, {28.985185185185184`, 
3.879934080019532`}, {30.099999999999998`, 2.3516342661824394`}};
```

then plot this points

```
ParametricPlot[BSplineFunction[pts][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I want to do something like this . I need to construct disk on each point, and it will like original graphic.

[image]

I tried first few steps:

```
 Show[Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, 1], 
 Cylinder[{{1, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0}}, 3], 
 Cylinder[{{2, 2, 0}, {3, 3, 0}}, 4]}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 0];

Plot[int[t], {t, 0, 30.1}]
```

[image]

```
dom = {t}~Join~int["Domain"][[1]]
```

> {t, 0., 30.1}

```
RevolutionPlot3D[int[t], Evaluate @ dom, RevolutionAxis -> "X", 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {pts[[;; , 1]]}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, -2, 0}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: `MaxRecursion ->6`

Answer (score 5):

You can create cylinders directly from the points.

```
Graphics3D@
 Table[Cylinder[{{pts[[i, 1]], 0, 0}, {pts[[i + 1, 1]], 0, 0}}, 
   pts[[i, 2]]], {i, 1, Length@pts - 1}]
```

[image]